# Create playlist Deezer API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, deezer

Im trying to create playlist for user using Deezer API but get error all the time "An active access token must be used to query information about the current use"

```
response = connection.post do |req|
  req.url "user/#{user_id}/playlists"
  req.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{acces_token}"
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = {
    title: name,
    public: public
  }.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in "access" in `"Bearer #{acces_token}"`

and

`Authorization Code` may need to be `Authorization`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here http://developers.deezer.com/api/user/playlists, this action needs a permission "manage_library" from the user to create a new playlist. Just ask for this permission like here http://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth and all will be fine normally.

Comment: well, i request this permission when user connects my app to deezer